# Illegal interface type in ByteBuddy

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I'm upgrading from ByteBuddy 0.6.15 to 1.2.3, and I'm getting "Illegal interface type" exceptions. I've managed to boil it down to this short bit of code:

```
@Test
public void bytebuddy() {
    new ByteBuddy()
            .subclass(Object.class)
            .implement(MyInterface.class)
            .make();
}

interface MyInterface {
    void doSomething();
}
```

In 0.6.15, this used to work, but in 1.2.3, I'm getting an exception: see below.

I don't understand what's illegal about the interface, or what I need to change to make it work. At first I thought it might be because I don't do anything with the `doSomething` method, but the same error occurs when the interface is completely empty.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal interface type interface nl.jqno.equalsverifier.internal.InstantiatorTest$MyInteface for class net.bytebuddy.renamed.java.lang.Object$ByteBuddy$qViwRZJu

  at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.InstrumentedType$Default.validated(InstrumentedType.java:694)
  at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.MethodRegistry$Default.prepare(MethodRegistry.java:530)
  at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.scaffold.subclass.SubclassDynamicTypeBuilder.make(SubclassDynamicTypeBuilder.java:153)
  at net.bytebuddy.dynamic.DynamicType$Builder$AbstractBase$Delegator.make(DynamicType.java:2508)
  at nl.jqno.equalsverifier.internal.InstantiatorTest.bytebuddy(InstantiatorTest.java:43)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
  at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
  at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
  at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
  at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
  at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
  at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
  at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
  at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
  at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
  at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
  at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With version 1.*, Byte Buddy added explicit validation what makes it easier to diagnose errors. In your case, you extend a package-private interface from a class that lives in another package. This means that the interface is not visible to the implementing class at runtime what will cause an `IllegalAccessError` eventually.

If you set the interface to be `public`, your example should work. Alternatively, you can put the generated class into the package of the interface. This happens automatically when you *subclass* the interface directly, i.e. `new ByteBuddy().subclass(MyInteface.class)`. Byte Buddy discovers that the supplied class is an interface and implements it. The implicit name will however be one that lives in the same package as the interface in this case.

Finally, type validation introduces some runtime overhead. You can disable validation by setting `new ByteBuddy().with(TypeValidation.DISABLED)` what you should ideally do in production but not in unit tests.

Finally, there is nothing illegal about the unit test, the wording was wrong, I changed the exception message to say *invisible*.

Comment: Setting the interface to public won't work in my case, unfortunately (in production, I don't have access to the interfaces I want to implement, and they're not always public). Setting `TypeValidation.DISABLED` does work for me, though. Also, thank you for changing the exception message: it's indeed much less confusing that way :). Thanks!

Comment: In this case, you should probably *subclass* the interface. This way, the implicit name of the generated class will be the same as that of the interface. This way, the implementation becomes legal. I extended my answer to explain this in more detail.

Comment: Haha, I was typing another comment about exceptions that I got when actually loading the generated class, when your edit appeared. Directly subclassing the interface took care of that exception, too! :)

Comment: Ah, this way I can remove the `TypeValidation.DISABLED`, too. Nice.

Comment: About that: you should disable this in production code. Having it enabled causes both a signature and a byte code level validation what can be rather expensive.

Comment: Just to be clear about the double negative: I should leave the call to `.with(TypeValidation.DISABLED)` in production, right?

Comment: Yes, in production, you should include the line.